# Liferay Hook - Get the User IP logging in

Tags: java, liferay

I have a Liferay-Hook to `ovrride` the `AuthenticateByEmailAddress(...)` method.

I want to get the IP address of the user is logging in and limit the access based on it.

How can I get the user IP in this method?
I use ServiceBuilder to make portlets.
I work by Tomcat.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what worked for me in Liferay 6.0.6.

In my hook I also changed default login.jsp. This was actually default login.jsp with two additional things. First, get IP from request:

```
<%String ip = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest).getRemoteAddr();%>
```

and add extra parameter:

```
<portlet:actionURL secure="<%= PropsValues.COMPANY_SECURITY_AUTH_REQUIRES_HTTPS || request.isSecure() %>" var="loginURL">
            <portlet:param name="saveLastPath" value="0" />
            <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/login/login" />
            <portlet:param name="requestIp" value="<%= ip %>" />
        </portlet:actionURL>
```

Now, in your overriden AuthenticateByEmailAddress(), you can get it from parameterMap:

```
String ip = parameterMap.get("requestIp")[0];
```

Comment: this is the only working answer so far - but not very satisfying since its not a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Just a thought, but if you want to limit based on IP, rather than doing this in your application, you can do it in the web server that you're deploying your application.

For instance, in Tomcat you can put security constraints in your web.xml.

[restrict access by ip](http://www.we3geeks.org/2012/03/02/tomcat-restricting-access-by-ip/)  this can also be done in JBoss too, it really depends on which web server you use, but this seems like the easiest solution rather than doing the filter in your application.

EDIT : after comments below, just do `PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request).getRemoteAddr();` in the method you're overriding and put your business logic there to see if the user changed ip (compare this IP with the persisted one etc).
Liferay already has some of this functionality [here](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/com/liferay/portal/service/UserLocalService.html#updateLastLogin%28long,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I want to create a custom field "IP" for Users and set it for each user. When a user tries to log in, I'll check the remote IP. If it was equal to the user custom IP, he/she log in otherwise raise error.

Comment: Ah I see, so if the user changes IP, you can inform them they're logging in from a different location?

Comment: Well, as you're overriding the authenticateByEmailAddress you're halfway there.  To get the IP address just do PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request).getRemoteAddr();

Comment: But I have no request object in this method. Is there any way to get the remote IP without request object?

Comment: Check the link I just added, you could just use the liferay functionality already in the object you're overriding.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this classes are made by Service Builder.
Then you can simply use:

```
String user = request.getRemoteUser();//take current logged in user ID
int userId = Integer.valueOf(user);//convert it into integer
User newUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId);//get the Liferay user using the user ID you get in the line above
userIp=newUser.getLoginIP();//after you have the current user take his LoginIP with the get method that Liferay has already
```

In the Liferay database you have table called `user_` there Liferay keeps all kind of info about the its users. Using the `UserLocalServiceUtil` you can take this info and use it as you want.

I hope that was helpful. Good luck with your portal :)

Comment: Since this class is a hook in the authentication chain, this answer is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay Portal, I've got the correct Client Ip address in the following way.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(portletRequest);
HttpServletRequest originalServletRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(request);
String ipAddress=originalServletRequest.getHeader("x-forwarded-for");
```

Comment: for me its not possible to get a FacesContext there.

Answer (score 0):

Since only one answer worked and I was not very pleased with that solution I did a little more digging.

Here is what I came up with:

Create a new filter and register it in your liferay. There you store the request in a thread local and remove it on the end of the request.

Afterwards you can just fetch the request from the Filter.

RequestFilter.java

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

    private static final ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest> REQUEST = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        HttpServletRequest req = REQUEST.get();
        if (req == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Attempt to fetch thread-local request outside of filter chain");
        }
        return req;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        REQUEST.set((HttpServletRequest)req);
        try {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } finally {
            REQUEST.remove();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

MyAuthFailure.java

```
public class MyAuthFailure implements AuthFailure {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(MyAuthFailure.class);

    @Override
    public void onFailureByEmailAddress(long companyId, String emailAddress, 
            Map<String, String[]> headers, Map<String, String[]> params) throws AuthException {
        logFailure(companyId, emailAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailureByScreenName(long companyId, String screenName, 
            Map<String, String[]> headers, Map<String, String[]> params) throws AuthException {
        logFailure(companyId, screenName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailureByUserId(long companyId, long userId, 
            Map<String, String[]> headers, Map<String, String[]> params) throws AuthException {
        logFailure(companyId, userId);
    }

    protected void logFailure(String user) {
        String ip = RequestFilter.getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
        LOG.error("User " + user + " tried to login from IP " + ip);
    }
}
```

liferay-hook.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_2_0.dtd">

<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
    <custom-jsp-dir>/WEB-INF/jsp</custom-jsp-dir>
    <servlet-filter>
        <servlet-filter-name>requestFilter</servlet-filter-name>
        <servlet-filter-impl>com.stackoverflow.RequestFilter</servlet-filter-impl>
    </servlet-filter>
</hook>
```

portal.properties

```
auth.failure=com.stackoverflow.MyAuthFailure
```